# Grabbing nested attributes with slimit - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get URL's from a site with a nested structure like this:

```
<script>
    var.model = {
       data: {
           "alist": [{
                'url': 'http://www.here.org'
           }]
       }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is, I can't seem to find a way to get through the tree that far. I have experience using BeautifulSoup4 but none using slimit, which I am trying to learn now.

```
def grabLinks(base, limit):
    base_url = requests.get(base)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(base_url.content, "html.parser")
    for script in soup.find_all("script", {'src': False}):
        if isinstance(script, NavigableString): continue
        tree = Parser().parse(script.text)
        for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree):
            if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and getattr(node.left, 'value', '') == "data":
                print(getattr(node.right, 'properties'))
```

I can go as far as getting to the name "alist" (with a whole lot of getattrs), but I cannot access the dictionaries of values inside it. If you need more information, please let me know.

**EDIT: Fixed! Updated code:**

```
def grabLinks(base, limit):
    base_url = requests.get(base)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(base_url.content, "html.parser")
    for script in soup.find_all("script", {'src': False}):
        if isinstance(script, NavigableString): continue
        tree = Parser().parse(script.text)
        for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree):
            if isinstance(node, a.Assign) and getattr(node.left, 'value', '') == "data":
                sibnode = getattr(node.right, 'properties')[0]
                print(sibnode.right.items[0].properties[0].right.value)
```

Comment: Did you try converting the string to a dict using `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: It says "module slimit.ast has no attribute literal_eval".

Comment: `import ast; ast.literal_eval(...)`

Comment: I got it to start working, thank you! I'm not a very good programmer so I may be a little slow with things sometimes, but thanks for your help!